# Does a closed form formula for the series $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^N {\frac{{1 + {x^{2n - 1}}}}{{1 + {x^{2n + 1}}}}}$ exist?

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

Does a closed form formula exist for the following series?

$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^N {\frac{{1 + {x^{2n - 1}}}}{{1 + {x^{2n + 1}}}}}$

Comment: Yes, it does, but weather we know it, that is a different question.

Comment: I'd like to know a closed form for the series above. I found similar series on Page 10 of this paper about quantum nonlocality: [https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.06317.pdf](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.06317.pdf)

Comment: @Arjang Why do you think that a closed form must necessarily exist?

Comment: Assuming $N \in \mathbb{N}$ the sum is finite and provided the denominator is not equal to zero the sum can always just be written out explicitly. I think what the OP is asking for is if this explicit sum can be written in a more compact form rather than as a sum of $N$ terms.

Comment: @TiwaAina : Lets say something has the closed form in terms of $\sin (x)$, would you say it is closed form? we can always bunch up number of infinite terms and give it a name. There are uncountably many functions, within that space for sure there is one that will coincide with values of this expression and we can name it.The correct question would have been is there a finite expression with constant number of terms expressible with elementary operations and functions. Then the answer might be no. without that restriction the answer is definitely yes.

Comment: @TiwaAina : a good example is the question that weather the quintic and above equations have closed form solutions, the answer is yes, but in terms of elliptic functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is "closed" form expression
$$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^p {\frac{{1 + {x^{2n - 1}}}}{{1 + {x^{2n + 1}}}}}=p+\frac{\left(1-x^2\right) }{x^2 \log \left(x^2\right)}\left(\psi _{x^2}^{(0)}\left(p+1-\frac{\log
   \left(-\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\log \left(x^2\right)}\right)-\psi
   _{x^2}^{(0)}\left(1-\frac{\log \left(-\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\log
   \left(x^2\right)}\right)\right)$$ where appears  the $q$ digamma function (have a look [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PolygammaFunction.html)).